# angular cli hangs while calling ng build --watch=true

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to build angular2 app with command `ng build --watch=true` and then it just hands and writes nothing in the console.

Here are my angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "name": "myapp"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../webapp",
      "assets": ["public"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "buildDev": "ng build --watch=true",
    "buildWatch": "ng build --watch=true",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.8",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this post is pretty old...

update Angular-CLI

You should build and watch just fine with the following:

```
ng build --watch
```